# Lebesgue measure of the projections of a compact set

Tags: lebesgue-measure, compactness, geometric-measure-theory

Does the following statement follow **easily** from any known theorem?

**Statement**: There exists a compact set $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that its projection to the $x$-axis is the $[0,1]$ interval, but in **all** other directions its projections are (Lebesgue) nullsets.

**Context:** I think I created a proof for this and I wonder whether I found something new.

Comment: If you are talking about orthogonal projection,then by Marstrand's Projection theorem, if the Hausdorff dimension of $K$ is larger than $1$ then the projection of the set at almost every line that passes through the origin has positive one dimensional Lebesgue measure...So your set must have  dimension  $\leq 1$..I do not know how much this helps you though..I hope so.

Comment: Yes, it's about orthogonal projections. I was aware of this projection theorem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The "venetian blind" construction (Theorem 6.15 in Falconer, The Geometry of Fractal Sets, 1986) gives a compact set of positive $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure that projects in every direction on a null set. Maybe a modification of that proof could give one "surviving" direction where the sets projects onto an interval. I don't know of any direct application of a theorem to obtain the result though. Just to mention another interesting result, Theorem 7.11 in the reference above shows that you can prescribe the projection of your set (up to null sets) on almost every direction.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. There exists such a set. For direct proof, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086908000066
(Appendix A)

Moreover, Michel Talagrand proved the following generalization of this:

Let $K$ be a compact set. Let $f_K: S^1\to \mathbb{R}$, $f_K(\alpha)=\lambda(proj_\alpha(K))$ (the Lebesgue-measure of the orthogonal projection in the direction $\alpha$).
Then the functions which can be obtained in the form $f_K$ for some compact set $K$ are exactly the nonnegative upper semicontinuous functions.

Reference: Sur la mesure de la projection d'un compact et certaines familles de cercles" Bull. Sci. Math. (2) 104 (1980), no. 3, 225–231.

I wasn't able to read the article yet. However many experts cite it so it should be ok.